# PouchDB with Couchbase sync-gateway not stable. Is it advised to use these two in a production stack?

Tags: pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

We are using pouchDB with couchBase sync gateway for a new application. In general it works, but we are finding it not stable. There are three issues for us

1. The unavailability of bulk processing through the sync gateway. Is there some solution for this?
2. We find that the couchBase sync gateway sometimes stop processing some requests.

It seems that this is related to the following error in the sync gateway logs:

```
_time=2017-11-01T01:48:47.168+02:00 _level=ERROR _msg= Unable to decode response read tcp nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:41006->nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:8091: read: connection reset by peer
_time=2017-11-01T01:48:47.168+02:00 _level=INFO _msg= Trying with http://subdomain.domain.net:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/kwantu_apps
2017-11-01T01:48:47.169+02:00 WARNING: Bucket Updater for bucket kwantu_apps returned error: Get http://subdomain.domain.net:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/kwantu_apps: dial tcp nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:8091: getsockopt: connection refused -- base.GetCouchbaseBucket.func1() at bucket.go:405
2017-11-01T01:48:47.169+02:00 WARNING: Lost TAP feed for bucket kwantu_apps, with error: Get http://subdomain.domain.net:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/kwantu_apps: dial tcp nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:8091: getsockopt: connection refused -- rest.(*ServerContext)._getOrAddDatabaseFromConfig.func1() at server_context.go:352
```

Does anybody have some suggestion or experience with this. If we restart the sync gateway, then all is well.

3. We have cases in which the documents streamed by the sync gateway to the local pouchdb installation is not completed, but in the console of the browser, (chrome in this case) the following error occurs ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING implying that the document was truncated. In some cases it seems that the replication pointer is set to true (it might not be related to this error in the logs) and then the document is not present on the local device, even though the sync is complete.

Please suggest how we can stabilise this. If not, is it advised to use the pouchdb - couchbase sync gateway in a production stack?